# wget loop to all the lines (url) in textfile and download Windows

Tags: python, windows, loops, url, wget

I have a simple task but cannot make my code work. I want to loop over the URLs listed in my textfile and download it using wget command in Python. Each URL are placed in separate line in the textfile.

Basically, this is the structure of the list in my textfile:

http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODIS_Composites/MOLT/MOD11C3.005/2000.03.01/MOD11C3.A2000061.005.2007177231646.hdf

http://e4ftl01.cr.usgs.gov//MODIS_Composites/MOLT/MOD11C3.005/2014.12.01/MOD11C3.A2014335.005.2015005235231.hdf

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oubyh.png]

all the URLs are about 178 lines. Then save it in the current working directory.

Below is the initial code that I am working:

```
import os, fileinput, urllib2 as url, wget
os.chdir("E:/Test/dwnld")
for line in fileinput.FileInput("E:/Test/dwnld/data.txt"):
    print line
    openurl = wget.download(line)
```

The error message is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "E:\Python_scripts\General_purpose\download_url_from_textfile.py", line 5, in <module>
    openurl = wget.download(line)   File "C:\Python278\lib\site-packages\wget.py", line 297, in download
    (fd, tmpfile) = tempfile.mkstemp(".tmp", prefix=prefix, dir=".")   File "C:\Python278\lib\tempfile.py", line 308, in mkstemp
    return _mkstemp_inner(dir, prefix, suffix, flags)   File "C:\Python278\lib\tempfile.py", line 239, in _mkstemp_inner
    fd = _os.open(file, flags, 0600) OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: ".\\MOD11C3.A2000061.005.2007177231646.hdf'\n.frbfrp.tmp"
```

Comment: Your filename contains a linefeed character (`'\n'`). Use `openurl = wget.download(line.strip())` to remove the whitespace.

Comment: @eryksun is correct. I also had a hard time debugging the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `urllib.urlretrieve`. Check the documentation here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve

Comment: Hi alexm, thanks for your reply. urllib works. But can you help me solve this little bit of problem. as of now the urllib is downloading the file but placing it in temporary folder. I want to place it in my current working directory with filename the same as the basename of my file. Below is the modified code:

Comment: Hi alexm, thanks for your reply. urllib works. But can you help me solve my problem. As of now the urllib is downloading the file but placing it in temporary folder. I want to place it in my current working directory with filename the same as basename of my file. I am running it but it throws an error: IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: 'MOD11C3.A2000061.005.2007177231646.hdf\n'. Basically, what I did was create an output variable which contains the output path and the basename of each URL. This is the line of code with problem openurl = urllib.urlretrieve(line,output).Thanks

Comment: You can place the file where you want by doing something like this: ```urllib.urlretrive('http://yourlink.com/file.pdf', '/path/to/local_file.pdf')```